# How to get the average in SQL with conditional parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, average

I have to get the average of collection of data and i have the idea but don't know how to execute this query:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(successRate)
FROM 
    usb_compliance
WHERE 
    ATC = 'CMB'
ORDER BY 
    date DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
```

Like this I want to get the average of `successRate` using the conditions above.

Please help me.

Comment: Having `ORDER BY` in your query as it stands is pointless because you will only get back one record.  Please update your question with a human-readable of what you are trying to do.

Comment: i wanna get average of successRate in resent three days thats why in=m using `ORDER BY` and `OFFSET`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ORDER BY is mandatory to use OFFSET and FETCH clause. [link here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: what you want last 3 transaction average ya last 3 days average?

Comment: Are you missing a GROUP BY clause?

Comment: @learningNew but I'm pretty sure it'll apply only after the average has been calculated. Subselect needed probably, though this is a very strange way to set limits for dates.

Comment: What you want to achieve is unclear but you should use group by with correct column(based on your desired result) to get this working.

Comment: i want to get the average of every three days so please help me to modify this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate your query.
Try this:

```
DECLARE @offset int = 0

SELECT AVG(successRate)
FROM
(
    SELECT successRate
    FROM usb_compliance
    WHERE ATC='CMB'
    ORDER BY date DESC
    OFFSET @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
) derivedTable
```

Comment: thank you, but i want to get the average of each 3 days that why im using `OFFSET` clause not TOP 3, is there any ways to get ???